# NStimer and UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have UINavigationController based app with two views. On the first view there is a NStimer which run for about 3 seconds and display random integer. 
When I switch to the second view and then back to the first the timer did not fire. 
How to fire the timer when I back to the first view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put ur Timer code on ViewDidAppear function

Comment: Can you recommend me some other solution, because viewDiDAppear is not called on push or pop view controller ?